# Loop through a two-dimensial array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am making an array and ran into a problem I don't know how to loop through a two-dimensial array.

This is my array:

```
$kaarten = array
(
  array("test",12.99),
  array("test1",129.99),
  array("test2",99.99)
);
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nested foreach would do it:

```
foreach($kaarten as $subArray)
{
    foreach($subArray as $subValue)
    {
        echo $subValue;
    }
}
```

If you don't need to loop the sub array, then you can directly access the values:

```
foreach($kaarten as $subArray)
{
    echo $subArray[0]; // test
    echo $subArray[1]; // 12.99
}
```

More info: [`foreach` on the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Hi, Thx for that answer that work for me, but now I got another question if you don't mind. Now the array info is embedded in the php code but I want to enter it myself in input fields, could you explain to me how I do this. A little example is that I start with 2 input fields (1. name 2. price) and that there is a button with "add one more" and that if you press it 2 new field popup with name and price. and so on. Hope you or someone else can help me with this.

Comment: Dennis, I recommend starting a new question because it sounds like it differs a lot from this one. Plus a new question will get much more attention, try to include the HTML that you generate and any related code.